# Rails Presenter - Interacting with 2 different models that share the same attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encapsulation, single-responsibility-principle, presenter

I have 2 models in a large Rails app `room` and `inquiry`. They both share an attribute/column `cancellation_policy`.

At the point at the point at which an inquiry (alias: booking) is made the `cancellation_policy` is copied from the `room.cancellation_policy` to `inquiry.cancellation_policy`.

---

I currently have a `RoomPresenter` that is initialized with a `room` object like this:

```
  def initialize(room, current_user = nil)
    @room = room
    @current_user = current_user
  end
```

This presenter does various things to 'present' a `room`. I recently however added a bunch of methods such as:

```
 def cancellation_policy_type
 def get_cancellation_policy_text_with_formatting
 etc.
```

In various RoomControllers (across different namespaces) I can then instantiate with `@room_presenter = RoomPresenter.new(@room)` and call methods in the relevant views as expected with `@room_presenter.  def cancellation_policy_type` for example.

---

I feel that I can take the following approach

```
class RoomPresenter
  # gives me access to RoomPresenter#cancellation_policy (see below)
  include RoomPresenters::CancellationPolicy

  def initialize(room)
    @room = room
  end
end

# app/presenters/room_presenters/cancellation_policy.rb
module RoomPresenters
  module CancellationPolicy
    def cancellation_policy
      ###
    end
  end
end
```

Which would separate out the `room` presenter methods from the `room.cancellation_policy` in a logical way but this doesn't solve issue between `Room` and `Inquiry` and a desire to not confused the two different classes.

---

However my main question/cluelessness comes when it comes to incorporating this across both the inquiry model and the room model. The following all seem very wrong to me:

```
class InquiryPresenter (would be initialized with an inquiry).
  include RoomPresenters::CancellationPolicy
```

as equally:

```
class InquiryPresenter
  #lots of duplicated code doing the same thing/same methods.
```

---

I am trying to understand how best to organise this type of logic, but am not sure of the best approach.

The underlying output is extremely simple - each method is just outputting some plain text or html, but as the app grows further I see the need to make sure the `Presenters` adhere to the SRP.

Please let me know if further explanation, examples are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by creating a base class for your presenters to reduce the amount of duplication

```
class BasePresenter < Delegator

  def initialize(object)
    @object = object
  end

  # required by Delegator
  def __getobj__
    @object
  end

  def self.model_name
    self.name.chomp("Presenter")
  end

  def self.model_key
    self.model_name.underscore.to_sym
  end

  alias_method :__getobj__, :object

  # declares a getter based on the class name
  # UserPresenter -> #user
  alias_method :__getobj__, self.model_key
end
```

Using the [stdlib `Delegator`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/Delegator.html) as the base class means it will delegate missing methods to the wrapped object.

For example:

```
RoomPresenter.new(@room).id == @room.id
```

We also create a generic initializer and use `@object` for the internal storage. The internally stored object can be accessed by `#object` or a custom getter derived from the class name.

This will let you wheedle down on the amount of boilerplate in your presenters.

```
class RoomPresenter < BasePresenter
  include RoomPresenters::CancellationPolicy 
end

class InquiryPresenter < BasePresenter
  include RoomPresenters::CancellationPolicy
end
```

You can also create a mixin for your models that lets you do `@room.present` instead of `RoomPresenter.new(@room)`.

It would also let you get a presented collection by doing `@rooms.map(&:present)`.

```
module Presentable
  def present
    "#{self.class.name}Presenter".constantize.new(self)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive answer. Will be working on implementing this over the next few days!